# Issue - Cursor shifts focus to next textbox on iOS 12 IPA built on xcode 10.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, sencha-touch, ios12, xcode10.1

We have been using XCode 7.1 till now for creating IPA but since Apple has made official that the IPA submitted should be created from XCode 10 and above, we have created the same project using XCode 10.1 and 10.2. We are facing an issue in the IPA created by XCode 10.1 or 10.2 where in if we focus on one text box the cursor jumps to some other text box(usually the last in sequence). Also, the issue is replicable only in iOS12 and above.

**Application type**: Hybrid application(iOS and Android) built by IBM

MobileFirstPlatform 7.1

**JS framework**: Sencha Touch 2.3.2

**Corodova version**: 3.7.0

**Logs on touch**:
default 16:56:41.258862 -0400  [FATAL] [NONE] Uncaught Exception: TypeError: The TouchEvent.changedTouches getter can only be used on instances of TouchEvent at (compiled_code):220
default 16:56:41.267527 -0400  [FATAL] [NONE] Uncaught Exception: TypeError: The Event.target getter can only be used on instances of Event at (compiled_code):417
default 16:57:05.723232 -0400  [FATAL] [NONE] Uncaught Exception: TypeError: The TouchEvent.changedTouches getter can only be used on instances of TouchEvent at (compiled_code):220

Comment: Are you able to recreate the issue without Sencha Touch in place?Do you see the issue happening with a plain and simply Hybrid application that uses only html textbox and pure Javascript? This is to check if Sencha UI elements are misbehaving.